# CronTab Run only ONCE in a year

Tags: python, shell, cron

Here is my job

```
45 5 5 2 WED /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Saqib/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/commands/player.py "/static/media/fajr1.mp3" "Office Ustairs speaker"
```

Jobs looks fine, as I want it to run only once in a year...however i am using a module called "[croniter](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/)"...and it seems like it has a bug.

my job is SET to fire only **on wed at 5 45, Feb of 5th**. however when i use the **get_next()** method, it returns the next fire date of coming/next wednesday as well.

I need to fire it only ONCE.

my system is Linux Debian kernal.

Anyway around this?

Comment: I think you are missing a `*` at the end? `45 5 5 2 WED *`

Comment: I tried it, when i do it says invalid cron expression.https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Comment: Do we talk about linux cron record?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
0 45 5 5 2 ? * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Saqib/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/commands/player.py "/static/media/fajr1.mp3" "Office Ustairs speaker"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about UNIX/Linux cron record it should be like this:

```
45 5 5 2 * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Saqib/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/commands/player.py "/static/media/fajr1.mp3" "Office Ustairs speaker"
```

first you should use number, not name of the day of week. Then in cron relation between minutes, hours, days of month and months is **AND**. But day of week is in **OR** relation with days of month. So on your way the script will be executed on the desired date **AND** every Wednesday

Answer (score 0):

@Romeo Ninov has the right idea!

Check https://crontab.guru/#45_5_5_2_*

45 5 5 2 * = “At 05:45 on day-of-month 5 in February.”